# Count the total number of occurrences for each element of substrings in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset about Disney streaming service.

[image: Subset of dataset]

I am particularly interested in the 'cast' column. The data type is string
But I want to know for each cast members of a movie, how many times it appears.

```
| cast  | Number of occurrences |
| Winston Hibler  | 4  |
| Zac Efron       | 3  |
```

- Do I need to separate the cast members into many columns?
- Should I first change the data type to list?

I have removed observation that have NULL values

Comment: Provide the data in a text format and not as an image

Comment: Im sorry Im new to this platform, I will take note of it!

Answer (score 3):

You can split cast members into separate rows using `tidyr::separate_rows()`, then count:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

movies %>% 
  separate_rows(cast, sep = ", ") %>%
  count(cast)
```

```
# A tibble: 37 × 2
   cast                 n
   <chr>            <int>
 1 Ashley Tisdale       3
 2 Bella Thorne         1
 3 Chanelle Peloso      1
 4 Chang Liu            1
 5 Clancy Brown         1
 6 Daichi Harashima     1
 7 Devon Bostick        1
 8 Don Knotts           1
 9 Donnie Yen           1
10 Eden Espinosa        1
# … with 27 more rows
```

Data:

```
movies <- structure(list(title = c("Trail of the Panda", "Zapped", "Frenemies", 
"Tangled Before Ever After", "Diary Of A Wimpy Kid", "Diary of a Wimpy Kid: Rodrick Rules", 
"Chicken Little", "High School Musical 2", "High School Musical 3: Senior Year", 
"High School Musical", "Disney My Music Story: Yoshiki", "Mulan", 
"Wolfgang", "In Beaver Valley", "Nature's Half Acre", "Water Birds", 
"The Olympic Elk"), director = c("Zhong Yu", "Peter DeLuise", 
"Daisy Mayer", "Tom Caulfield, Stephen Sandoval", "Thor Freudenthal", 
"David Bowers", "Mark Dindal", "Kenny Ortega", "Kenny Ortega", 
"Kenny Ortega", "Kentaro Takayanagi", "Niki Caro", "David Gelb", 
"James Algar", "James Algar", "Ben Sharpsteen", "James Algar"
), cast = c("Zhong Yu, Zhang Qi, Daichi Harashima, Li Feng, Chang Liu", 
"Zendaya, Chanelle Peloso, Spencer Boldman", "Zendaya, Bella Thorne, Mary Mouser, Nick Robinson", 
"Zachary Levi, Mandy Moore, Eden Espinosa, Clancy Brown", "Zachary Gordon, Robert Capron, Rachel Harris, Steve Zahn", 
"Zachary Gordon, Devon Bostick, Rachael Harris", "Zach Braff, Garry Marshall, Don Knotts, Patrick Stewart", 
"Zac Efron, Vanessa Hudgens, Ashley Tisdale, Lucas Grabeel", 
"Zac Efron, Vanessa Hudgens, Ashley Tisdale, Lucas Grabeel", 
"Zac Efron, Vanessa Hudgens, Ashley Tisdale, Lucas Grabeel", 
"YOSHIKI", "Yifei Liu, Donnie Yen, Gong Li, Jet Li, Jason Lee", 
"Wolfgang Puck", "Winston Hibler", "Winston Hibler", "Winston Hibler", 
"Winston Hibler")), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```